# No such file or directory as on /usr/lib/sendmail (Ubuntu)

Tags: sendmail

I did many attempts to send mail using `mail` command as follows:

```
abdennour@pc: mail -v abd.tm@gmail.com
Subject: Hello World!
This is an email to myself.

Hope all is well.
.
Cc:
```

I get this error message:

```
/usr/lib/sendmail: No such file or directory
"/home/abdennour/dead.letter" 9/261 
. . . message not sent.
```

Comment: `sudo apt-get install mailutils` is all you needed.

Answer (score 6):

I found that if I installed both mailutils AND sendmail, that error went away and sending the contents of a file as an email worked:

```
sudo apt-get install mailutils
sudo apt-get install sendmail
cat /tmp/somefile.txt | mail -s "My subject " myemailname@example.com
```

Comment: Just installing `sendmail` worked for me.

Answer (score 1):

Alternatively, install mutt (`apt-get install mutt`) which gives you a nicer (but still command line) interface

Answer (score 0):

I was seeing the same error when trying to send a test message using a freshly installed copy of mailx.

The problem was that I named the configuration file /etc/mail.rc instead of /etc/nail.rc. Renaming it to /etc/nail.rc solved the problem.

Mailx used to be called nail and it seems like the global configuration file keeps the legacy name.